# White text on white background for some system windows

Tags: 20.04, themes, gnome-shell, colors, appearance

I have a problem with some windows, usually install wizards, which display a white text on a white background. See for example the EULA of the attached picture, unreadable.

[image]

I tried changing themes, but no result.
I also looked within Gnome tweaks, but no success.
Do you know how to fix the problem?

As theme I use Yara-dark default with GNOME Shell 3.36.4 under Ubuntu 20.04.

EDIT: I did some extra tests and the problem is present only with dark themes (both Adwaita Dark and Yaru Dark). If I change to non-dark themes (both Yaru and Adwaita) the problem is gone. Notably, when I change the theme, all windows (i.e. gnome shell and nautilus) immediately change theme; on the contrary, widows like the above require a restart to load the new colors.

Comment: Provide information on customizations you did to the system. A customization could be at the origin of the problem.

Comment: No customization, I use Yaru-dark default theme.

Comment: Would be good to add that information to your post (although one could guess from the picture as well).

Comment: It probably does not happen with the default theme? Does it also happen with, say Adwaita Dark, the "reference" theme of Gnome Shell? If no, then it is a Yaru dark issue, if yes, then it is either a GTK theming issue or an issue with how the software applies themes.

Comment: Good point! I did some extra tests. The problem is present only with dark themes (both Adwaita Dark and Yaru Dark). If I change to non-dark themes (both Yaru and Adwaita) the problem is gone. Notably, when I change the theme, all windows (i.e. gnome shell and nautilus) immediately change theme; on the contrary, widows like the above require a restart to load the new colors. 
I suppose then that with a dark theme, some variable that should invert black and white are "faulty", i.e. when I change to dark theme text becomes white but background doesn't change. where is this behavior set?

Comment: Of note, this happens with different types of windows, so I'd rather say it's a GTK issue than specifically on how the SWs apply themes. On the contrary could be that that those wizard do not have a variable to color the background (usually always white).

Comment: This is all very relevant information for tracking the problem: add this information to your question. Indicate more specifically which windows of which applications cause issues: then, someone can also test.